# Predefined data formats supported by ClipboardData() Object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

What are predefined data formats supported by the `ClipboardData()` Object other than Text?

Comment: Some people Dont even read the question and vote down to close questions. I hope god only can help them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536744%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it supports text (String) only