# Clipboard binary data in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, binary, clipboard, zeroclipboard

Is programmatic access to binary clipboard data (files etc.) possible in well, any version of Internet Explorer?

I'm aware plain text can be accessed via window.clipboardData.getData('Text').

The plan is to be able to copy an email from MS Outlook 2010, paste into a web form and upload the email.

I've looked into a number of flash plugins and they only seem to be able to read text data from the clipboard, ZeroClipboard etc.

A backup solution is to write an MS Outlook addin which adds a "Copy for web" option which gives a base64 copy of the email file, allowing the use of plaintext for decoding back to a file on upload.

I'd really rather access the file directly, anyone got any pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Predefined data formats supported by ClipboardData() Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332016/predefined-data-formats-supported-by-clipboarddata-object)